# Difference between methods, computed properties, and filters?

Tags: vue.js

I'm just getting back into Vue development and am a bit rusty on certain topics. Could somebody explain the difference between methods, computed properties, and filters, as well as describe when each should be used?

It is my understanding that methods are invoked every time some change is made to the state, whereas computed properties and filters are invoked only when change is made to a specific variable that they are using. Is this correct?

Is it correct to say that filters are essentially the same as computed properties, but can take parameters, which computed properties cannot?

I am grateful for any help with my understanding of this

Comment: For computed properties have a look in this doc : https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html, For filters : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Comment: Methods are invoked every time you invoke them, regardless of a state, so are filters. There is no separate filter functionality in Vue 3, so they are basically methods with special template syntax.